# Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the MacLaurin 6th degree polynomial for the function $ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}}$.

My first idea was to derive the series expansion of $\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{arsinh}(2x)$, but that seems too complicated. The next idea was the binomial series. As far as I know, the binomial coefficient was not yet introduced in the lecture.

I am slowly running out of ideas because the task explicitly requires the modification of known series.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1):

As $4x^2\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow 0$, you can use the Maclaurin polynomial of **third degree** of $(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ (which is very easy to calculate, also using the definition, as it's not difficult to write the third derivative of $(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$) and substitute $4x^2$ to $t$.
From
$$
(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{3}{8}t^2-\frac{5}{16}t^3+o(t^3)
$$
you get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}=(1+4x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1-2x^2+6x^4-20x^6+o(x^6)
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x) = \frac{1}{{(1 + 4x^2)}^{1/2}}=\left(1+ 4x^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is possible to use [Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) for real power $-\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\left(1+ 4x^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}4^{k}x^{2k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$